# Sub-query Causing MySQL crash on MySQL 5.5 , working fine on 5.7 and mariabd

Tags: mysql, database

I've created a query to get info from some table

```
SELECT file,thumb FROM dl2_images WHERE (id) IN 
( SELECT MIN(id)
  FROM dl2_images
  WHERE file IN (226,225,223,222,221,220,219,218,217,214,213,212,211,210,209,208,201,198,197,196,195,194,192,191,190,181,145,144,140,138,137,136,132,125,122,121,119,118,116,43,40,39)
  GROUP BY file
)
```

The query runs fine on MySQL 5.7 and mariabd but causes MySQL to crash on MySQL 5.5 .. I can't find any reason .. any thoughts on that ?
Edit : it may be ( and most likely ) the version is not the issue .. what configuration / thing may be the problem ?

Comment: When you say *"to crash on ... 5.5..."*, does that mean that the mysql processes are killed?  Or the SQL is not executed?  Either way, you need to provide logs from the server and/or from the tool you use to run the query.  Table definition and sample data set are great to help on a query as well.

Comment: how can we reproduce such an issue?

Comment: Post complete text results of  EXPLAIN .... and  SHOW INDEX FROM dl2_images, please.   We will have number of rows, cardinality information by index for this table.  And related part of error log.